# Optional `new` operator

Tags: jquery

Reading through the jQuery documentation about the event object and its constructor `$.Event()` I see:

> The `new` operator is optional [when calling the constructor].

That's cool! How did the jQuery people pull such a trick?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

John Resig explains this pretty well: http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#36 and http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#38

Basically, `Event` is a function and an object (functions are objects). The first line of Event checks if it is being called as a function or as an instance of the Event object (with the new operator).

If you are looking for specifically how jQuery does it, look at line 3134-3138 of the [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js):

```
jQuery.Event = function( src, props ) {
    // Allow instantiation without the 'new' keyword
    if ( !this.preventDefault ) {
        return new jQuery.Event( src, props );
    }
```

And explanation for this is on [the jQuery forms](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/why-does-jquery-event-use-preventdefault-as-an-instance-test).

Basically, on lines 3178-3194 the preventDefault event is added to the Event prototype. If the event is instantiated with `new` it will be given this preventDefault method. Otherwise, it won't be defined.

Comment: What is `this.preventDefault`?

Answer (score 3):

Any user-defined JavaScript function can be called either with or with the `new` operator. Without `new` it works just as an ordinary function (because that's what it is). With `new`, the interpreter creates a fresh object with the prototype set appropriately, and makes that object the `this` parameter of the call. This fresh object is then the result of the `new` operator -- *except* if the function body `return`s a value explicitly; then then returned value governs.

So if you write

```
function foo() {
   return { bar: 42 };
}
```

you can call it either without or with `new` -- there's no difference because the body always explicitly returns a value, and never uses its `this`.